# Intel parallel studio warning on VS2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005, intel-parallel-studio

I installed the intel parallel studio and used it. But when I ran the application, I got a message in the Output section of Visual Studio 2005 that said

> “Data collection has stopped after reaching the configured limit of 10
>   MB of raw data. The target will continue to run, but no further data
>   will be collected. The data collection stopped since the data size
>   limit of (10 Mb) is reached. The application is running but no data is
>   collected.”

Does anyone has any idea why this message is coming and is it like if I continue running my application the data will not be collected. I am not sure how to configure the settings as this is the first time I am using any such tool for finding performance hotspots.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to know what version of Parallel Studio you are using and which collection you are running (since different collector use different settings).

Assuming you are running Amplifier collection:

- Click *"Project Properties"* button (on toolbar or under *"Start"* button on left side panel).
- In *"Target"* tab expand *"Advanced"* section.
- There is *"Collection data limit"* option. You could increase it as appropriate. In latest versions of Parallel Studio it is increased to 500 MB by default.

You could set data limit to zero for unlimited collection. I don't recommend this since you may run out of disc space quickly. This is also the reason why this option is here - unlimited collection produce huge amounts of raw data.